# Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't boot anymore. Nore from HDD, nore from live USB. Win XP boots fine

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, bootloader, boot-failure

Booting normally, it drops my in a small shell... something like initframs, i'm not quite sure.
Booting in recovery mode dropes me to the same shell but constantly writes out error messages. Something that had to do with a bad sector on /dev/sdb. 
So i said... ok. A fresh live usb flash would do the trick. I can run HDD utilities from it to repair things.
WRONG. The live flash stumbled on the same error (seemingly).

[image]

After these errors the ubuntu logo appeared with the blinking dots that never finished blinking. The flash's light didn't indicate any activity on the data channels. Flash works fine on another pc though.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it got corrupted, You said the LiveCD doesn't boot either? I would try to install 11.10 and do upgrade not wipe and reinstall.

Comment: Sorry I would try booting by liveCD and see if it will let you boot into that.

Comment: livecd from usb didn't boot because of the errors (see screenshot). I couldn't upgrade it.


EDIT:Oh, my bootable usb flash had 11.10 on it.